# i need to restrict users to access my web application

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

hi am creating one web application,in that application i want to restrict number of accessing users. For eg: only 4 users can access the application if exceeds 4 users it shows error message like limit exceeds until anyone of the 4 users will logout. if anyone of 4 users logout means the count will be 3 so some other 1 user can access the application.Another one best example: reputation in stackoverflow page if someone give one minus point it will reflect in everyone's page.

index page:

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<html>
<body>

    <form method="get" action="PageHitCounter">
        <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
    </form>

</body>

<%

 if(session.getAttribute("ht")!=null)
    {

    String Aht= session.getAttribute("ht").toString();
    int hitCount=Integer.parseInt(Aht); 
    System.out.println("hit count in login"+hitCount);

    session.setAttribute("hitCount",hitCount);

    }

else {
    int hitCount = 0;

    session.setAttribute("hitCount",hitCount);
    System.out.println("new session count"+hitCount);
}



%>


</html>
```

servlet page:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
//import java.sql.Date;
//import java.sql.SQLException;
//import java.util.*;
//import java.sql.*;

public class PageHitCounter extends HttpServlet{

  private int hitCount; 

  public void init() 
  { 
     // Reset hit counter.
    hitCount = 0;
  } 

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {

      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
      // Set response content type

      response.setContentType("text/html");
      // This method executes whenever the servlet is hit 
      // increment hitCount 


      if(session.getAttribute("hitCount")!= null){

          String Aht= session.getAttribute("hitCount").toString();
          int hitCount=Integer.parseInt(Aht); 

          System.out.println(hitCount);
          hitCount++; 
          System.out.println("after increment"+hitCount++);


          if(hitCount <= 5)
          {
          System.out.println("if");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          String title = "Total Number of Hits";
          String docType =
          "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
          "transitional//en\">\n";
          out.println(docType +
            "<html>\n" +
            "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
            "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
            "<form action='Logout.jsp'>"+
            "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
            "<h2 align=\"center\">" + hitCount + "</h2>\n" +
           "<input type='submit' value='logout'/>"+
            "</body></html>"); 
           }

      }

      else 
          {

        System.out.println("else");
        hitCount++; 
        session.setAttribute("ht", hitCount);


      if(hitCount <= 4)
      {
      System.out.println("aa");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String title = "Total Number of Hits";
      String docType =
      "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
      "transitional//en\">\n";
      out.println(docType +
        "<html>\n" +
        "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
        "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
        "<form action='Logout.jsp'>"+
        "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
        "<h2 align=\"center\">" + hitCount + "</h2>\n" +
       "<input type='submit' value='logout'/>"+
        "</body></html>");


      }

      }

/*      else
      {
          destroy(); 
          response.sendRedirect("Logout.jsp");

      }*/

  }



  public void destroy() 
  { 

     // hitCount -= 1;
      // This is optional step but if you like you
      // can write hitCount value in your database.
  } 
}
```

logout page:

```
<%
session.removeAttribute("hitCount");
//session.invalidate(); 

   String ht1=session.getAttribute("ht").toString();
int ht2=Integer.parseInt(ht1);
System.out.println("hit count before"+ht1);
if(ht2 != 0)
{
    ht2 -= 1;
    System.out.println("hit count after"+ht2);
}

session.setAttribute("ht", ht2);  


%>
<h2>Session Destroyed successfully.. </h2>


<a href="index1.jsp">Click here to go Back</a>
```

now what problem am facing is the count will not reduce because the count will be in session but in logout page i need to invalidate session so i wont get that count properly. So please someone help me.

Comment: Don't use session it's new for each user, keep the `hitCount` at application scope using `ServletContext` shared among all the users

Comment: @Arvind yeah I too think that only but one particular user logout means that count want to be 3 users and for another user the count will be shown 3 users

Comment: implement a filter which process the incoming request have a counter to increment on login and decrement on logout if the count is less then 10 redirect to login page or else redirect to some error page

Comment: @SparkOn yeah thank you. I dont have idea about filter can u send any link for clear reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to restrictions your application to a maximum of 4 sessions. You should keep the number of active sessions in a `ServletContext` attribute. You access it easily from a servlet (`getServletContext()`) or from a JSP (`${application.attrName}`)

You must use it at login, but cannot rely on a logout page because a session will simply expire if a user forgets to logout. You will have to setup a session listener to correctly maintain the session count.

The session listener could look like :

```
@WebListener
public class SessionCountListener implements HttpSessionListener, ServletContextListener {
    private ServletContext ctx;
    private int sessionCount = 0;
    private static final String DEFAULT_ATTR = "sessionCount";
    private String attr;
    private static final String PARAM_NAME = "session_count.attr_name";

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // store servletContext
        ctx = sce.getServletContext();
        // try to get attribute name in config
        attr = ctx.getInitParameter(PARAM_NAME);
        if ((attr == null) || attr.isEmpty()) {
            attr = DEFAULT_ATTR;
        }
        sessionCount = 0;
        ctx.setAttribute(attr, sessionCount);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ctx.removeAttribute(attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        countUpdate(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        countUpdate(-1);
    }

    synchronized private void countUpdate(int delta) {
        sessionCount += delta;
        ctx.setAttribute(attr, sessionCount);
    }
}
```

With this listener, the session count is stored by default under the attribute name `sessionCount`, but it can be configured with a context parameter of name `session_count.attr_name`. And all accesses to the variable `sessionCount` are correctly synchronized since several requests can create or close sessions at the same time.

You will find all references on [Java EE 6 Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html)

Comment: i understood but i dont have any idea about Context and listener can u send any link for clear reference. Thank you.

Comment: ©Anand The servlet context is a single (java) web application on a single server or more exactly container). I will add more details before tomorrow.